# How to insert using the result of another query in rethinkdb?

Tags: rethinkdb

Using the rethinkdb data explorer

```
r.db('exports').table('requests')
```

fetches

```
{
  "options": {
    "params": {
      "foo": "bof"
      "sort": "desc",
      "page": 6
    }
  } ,
  "url": "https://url1.tld/"
} 

{
  "options": {
    "auth": {
      "type":  "basic" ,
      "pass":  "dnkykngcntry1" ,
      "user":  "diddy"
    } ,
    "params": {
      "foo": "bar"
      "sort": "asc",
      "page": 3
    }
  } ,
  "url": "https://url2.test/"
} 

...
```

---

Now i'd like to do this

```
r.db('exports').table('responses').insert(
  r.db('exports').table('requests').map(req => ({
    requestId: req('id'),
    requestedAt: r.now(),
    response: r.http(req('url'), req('options'))
  }))
)
```

Getting this error:

```
e: Expected 1 argument (not including options) but found 2.
```

---

If I call the [`r.http`](https://www.rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/http/) function with the values from one of the `request` documents, everything works fine

```
// http command syntax
// r.http(url[, options]) → value
// r.http(url[, options]) → stream

r.http("https://url1.tld/", {
    "params": {
      "foo": "bof"
      "sort": "desc",
      "page": 6
    }
  })
// <response text>
```

Why doesn't it work with `req('url')` and `req('options')` in the loop then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a RethinkDB expert, but I probably can make a simple shallow analysis/fix of the issue (assuming you're working with JavaScript).

> Why doesn't it work with `req('url')` and `req('options')` in the loop then?

I don't think it's a loop-related issue, and it's more likely the way RethinkDB deals with ReQL expressions and probably optional arguments (if taking the error message into account).
Both `req('url')` and `req('options')` are ReQL expressions and can be instantiated manually using `r.expr(...)`.

Consider the following code that faces with your issue as well:

```js
// These two are your req('url') and req('options') equivalents respectively
const url = r.expr('https://postman-echo.com/get');
const options = r.expr({ params: { foo: 1, bar: 2 } });
// ...
r.http(url, options);
```

> e: Expected 1 argument (not including options) but found 2.

Okay, let's try to run it without the `options` argument using simple `r.http(url)`, and this is what it gets:

```js
{
    "args": { },
    "headers": {
        "accept": "*/*",
        "accept-encoding": "deflate, gzip",
        "host": "postman-echo.com",
        "user-agent": "RethinkDB/2.3.2-windows-beta-472-ga2117b",
        "x-forwarded-port": "443",
        "x-forwarded-proto": "https"
    } ,
    "url": "https://postman-echo.com/get"
}
```

I believe `r.expr(...)`-instantiated ReQL values are clashed with the `options` upon is-this-options detection (maybe due to the same behavior that's caused with `undefined`).
All you have to do is wrap your document properties in a raw JavaScript object because RethinkDB seems to work perfectly with nested properties.

```
r.http(url, rebuildOptions(options));
```

where `rebuildOptions` can be implemented as a fairly limited function due to the `r.http()` API restrictions, for example:

```js
const rebuildOptions = options => ({
    method: options('method').default('GET'), // default GET is fine for method
    // auth: don't know how to deal with auth - we cannot assign undefined to the property and cannot provide the default auth too
    params: options('params').default({}), // default {} is fine for params
    header: options('header').default({}), // the headers will be merged in the final request
    // data: don't know how to deal with data too - we can analyze options('method'), but cannot assign a good default value
});
```

Dirty and weak.
I can also suggest a more "hackish" and more generic implementation I've discovered while inspecting the ReQL values structure:

```js
// This looks to work with any ReQL values
const unexpr = expr => Object.assign({}, expr.optargs);
```

```js
r.http(url, unexpr(options));
```

Now both implementations can return:

```
{
    "args": {
        "bar": "2",
        "foo": "1"
    } ,
    "headers": {
        "accept": "*/*",
        "accept-encoding": "deflate, gzip",
        "host": "postman-echo.com",
        "user-agent": "RethinkDB/2.3.2-windows-beta-472-ga2117b",
        "x-forwarded-port": "443",
        "x-forwarded-proto": "https"
    } ,
    "url": "https://postman-echo.com/get?bar=2&foo=1"
}
```

It looks like a design imperfection (`r.expr()` without its "unwrapper" counterpart, if RethinkDB ever needs it though) or an optional arguments detection bug, and probably worth to be submitted to the [RethinkDB issue tracker](https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb/issues) at least to get the RethinkDB team feedback.

Comment: I wish I could express how happy this answer makes me – it appears we took the same path in trying to figure this out – i got it working with `r.http(req('url'), { auth: req ('options') ('auth'), params: req ('options') ('params') })` – which is a worse version of your `rebuildOptions` solution – I had the same hunches wrt "optional arguments detection bug" and `r.expr`'s design imperfection... so that makes your `unexpr` solution *very* attractive; and quite unique too; a very elegant work-around – thanks heaps ^_^

Comment: I [submitted an issue here](https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb/issues/6523) – perhaps you'd like to contribute your post to the github thread too ? I'm going to mark this question as answered.

Comment: I was informed by SamHughes that `unexpr` only works here because the object was constructed with `R.expr`; in the real query, this would **not** work – the `rebuildOptions` approach is the correct way to do this, but Sam also makes a note about optimising its performance with `.do`; see his answer for details

Answer (score 1):

Remember that you're constructing a query to send to the server, and the function `rebuildOptions` described above constructs an expression out of the "options" expression.  That could then potentially cause the server to reevaluate the `options` expression in three different places.  (And in practice, this would indeed happen.)  For query construction helper functions it is a good idea to construct a query using `r.do` to avoid reevaluation of the parameter expression, if the expression is used more than once in the larger expression built around it.

```
const rebuildOptions = options => options.do(x => ({
    method: x('method').default('GET'),
    params: x('params').default({}),
    header: x('header').default({}),
}));
```

As I mentioned in the Github issue it's an intentional design decision.  The optional arguments of a function have to be provided "statically," and different client drivers in different languages might not represent the optional arguments using a single dictionary.

Comment: ok this helps me understand a lot better; thanks for everything Sam